# TeamCity config

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy

We're pretty new to TeamCity at work. We have a build & deployment pckage setup which is using MSBuild/MSDeploy to ship changes to our web servers. However, we have a few issues (apologies for putting a few questions on the same post). For clarification our solutions looks like so:

- Project Folder

  - WebApp (includes .csproj file. Includes a folder called "media" - this folder is not in SVN)
  - Libraries (includes referenced assemblies)

Our issues:

- There is a specific folder within the Libraries folder that must be copied into the bin directory after build (because of an assembly redirect). We have always used a PostBuild event, however this doesnt work in TeamCity.
- The folder "media" within the WebApp folder is not included in SVN. When the TeamCity package is executed it deletes this folder. I would like to prevent TeamCity from deleting just this folder.
- When we run the TeamCity task, we get an ERROR_FILE_IN_USE error for one of the files teamcity is trying to delete during the sync task. I have read about using the app_offline.htm file to combat this - but quite how Im not sure.

I'm going to guess that some of these settings can be command line parameters in the msbuild job - I think it would be better to store these in the csproj file rather than just in teamcity if it is possible?

thanks in advance
Al

Answer (score 0):

A few questions on the information provided

1. Can you clarify what you mean by post-build command doesnt work? Does it fail or does it just not do what you expect?
2. How have you setup your post-build command? does it reference specific filepaths? TeamCity  executes MSBuild in the same was as you could from the command line or from visual studio.

Regarding the MSDeploy folder issue, you can configure MSDeploy with a Skip Action, here's a link to another post describing how to do this
[Prevent MSDeploy (selectively) from deleting folders on target IIS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607890/prevent-msdeploy-selectively-from-deleting-folders-on-target-iis-server)

Because MSDeploy is trying to deploy into a folder being used by IIS you are also seeing the file locking issue. There are two solutions
1. Add a teamcity step to stop IIS (using PowerShell) before deploying. This will cause downtime.
2. Deploy to a different folder and then switch IIS to point to your new folder. This is a much better solution as you also have roll back.

A much easier solution to all of this is to use a Deployment Tool such as Octopus Deploy to deploy your application. You can learn more about Octopus Deploy at http://octopusdeploy.com/